# Showing a particular function is onto

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Consider $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is given by $f(x) = x\cos(x)$, we want to show $f$ surjective. Usually these type of proofs aren't very difficult as you can isolate x in terms of y. In this case you can't do that, but we know that $-x \le x\cos(x) \le x$ so intuitively we know this function is surjective, but I am having trouble constructing a proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, observe that $f$ is continuous. Choose any $y\in\mathbb{R}$, and let $n_y\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|y| < 2n_y\pi$. Then
$$f(2n_y\pi) = 2n_y\pi \cos 2n_y\pi = 2n_y\pi > y$$
but
$$f((2n_y+1)\pi) = (2n_y+1)\pi \cos (2n_y+1)\pi = -(2n_y+1)\pi < y$$
and then you can use the intermediate value theorem on $[2n_y\pi,(2n_y+1)\pi]$ to show that there exists $x$ such that $f(x)=y$.

Comment: This was exactly along the lines of what I was thinking. I wasn't sure if there was a solution avoiding the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: I'm not sure to see how it'd go — if somebody has one, I'm clearly interested (it'll have to use the continuity of $f$ in some way, no matter how).

Comment: I doubt that there is a proof avoiding the use of IVT. To get one you would also have to prove that $\cos x:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow[-1, 1]$ is onto without using IVT. I don't know of a way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Let $y\in \Bbb R$. You want to find $x\in \Bbb R$ such that $f(x)=y$.

Define $g_y(x)=f(x)-y$. Now you can use the [intermediate value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) on $g_y$ to prove that $g_y(x)=0$ for some $x\in \Bbb R$ which implies that $f(x)=y.$